# Hack/HHVM with Apache 2.4 results in HTTP 503 and unlimited loading

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, fastcgi

I've tried to set up an Apache 2.4 on Debian Wheezy to make calls to [Hack/HHVM](http://hhvm.com) using mod_proxy / mod_proxy_fcgi according to [this](http://hhvm.com/blog/1817/fastercgi-with-hhvm) article.

The installation of HHVM was through the APT package manager. When I run a single .hack-file using

```
hhvm test.hack
```

with test.hack content

```
<?hh echo "test";
```

the output is as expected.

Now I start the HHVM fastcgi server using

```
hhvm --mode server -vServer.Type=fastcgi -vServer.Port=9001
```

and putting this to my testing vHost in the Apache configuration file:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*.hack(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001/home/web/test/$1
```

After restarting Apache, I verified that it works by requesting a .hack-file which does not exists. I get a `404 Not Found` from the HHVM fastcgi server, it looks different than the default Apache 404 page.

When I request my `test.hack`-file, then Apache starts 'loading forever'. If I kill the fastcgi in the background, it immediately stops loading and offers me the `test.hack` as a download with the content I entered (`<?hh echot "test";`).

I'm using PHP5-FPM with exactly the same `ProxyPassMatch` line, except the mime file extension and the port, of course. And it works perfectly there.

The `error.log` contains nothing special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing HHVM 3.0 which has been released today this issue has been fixed. Works without changing any of my configuration so this fault must be caused by HHVM 2.x.